# I want to get file size in javascript but not to use ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),There are another ways?

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        var filepath = "D:\\RD.xlsx";
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var file = fso.GetFile(filepath);
            var filesize = file.size;
    </script>
```

I want to get file size in javascript but not to use ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),There are another ways?